# endIconMode in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I'm working with TextInputLayout and inside TextInputEditText.
I used app:endIconMode in TextInputLayout, then distance from hint and baseline are bigger than before, how to retrieve this distance?
This is my code:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="@string/hint_phon_number">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="17"
                    android:textColor="#FF192331" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please include the images, to make the question more clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because, I use this project material library, then this error appear, when I delete import this library, all were well

Comment: We have to delete material library?